# pattern match search in vi editor

Tags: linux, search, count, vi

I would like to find **number of match result**
with `http://localhost:8080/MyProject/jsps/ErrorPage.jsp Incident ID`  in vi editor? 
How to do this?

i tried `:%s/http://localhost:8080/MyProject/jsps/ErrorPage.jsp Incident ID/&/gn` but it shows error **E488: Trailing characters**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have the separator `/` in the word you are looking for, so that the blocks get confused.

You can escape all the `/`, but it can be faster and cleaner to change the separator. For example, you can use `_`:

```
:%s_http://localhost:8080/MyProject/jsps/ErrorPage.jsp_&_gn
   ^                                                  ^ ^
```

Answer (score 1):

the syntax should be like below,

```
%s/http:\/\/localhost\:8080\/MyProject\/jsps\/ErrorPage.jsp\ Incident\ ID/&/gn
```

Note: you need to always scape "/, space"